# What device unique id should I use as key to encrypt some values

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption, sharedpreferences

I've read quite a few questions here but none really answered my question.

I know that the best place to store the key is serverside, but my app does not have a server. Also, asking for password each time the user starts the app is not an option either.

From what I've read, there are 2 places to actually store the data:

- `SharedPreference` but encrypt it: this means that a user with root can get access to xml file easy and if decompile apk can get to the actual value
- in a `sqlite database` but is really just a matter of using a sqlite db browser to read the data.

Basically I want to store 2 things:

- a token which can be reset by the user anytime by logging into a web browser
- the in app purchases purchased by the user.

For in app purchases I can fix this pretty simple: query on each app start the purchased items. This means that even if the app stores in SharedPreferences the values, for cases when querying fails, I still override this values if not the case.

One thing is decided: do not store them in plain text but encrpt it.
As for encryption, I was thinking of using some sort of unique id for each app installation as key for AES. Because here's the thing, for instance if I encrypt an in app purchase value with same hardcoded key on all devices, a SharedPreference value from a purchased device can be copied on a rooted device and get access to the app without paying. I want to avoid this, and by using maybe `Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID` can I simply encrypt something that would not be the same on any other device and more important, not even the developer has access to decryption. What key can I use that is device dependent and would allow encryption particular for that device. That means copying a backup to another device, would not work, because decryption would return different results.

I know that there are many questions on this and probably my question will be downvoted, but many android versions have changed since that questions.

The basics remain: how can I most securely store some values related to my android app?

Comment: I would not store the app purchases on the device, because this means to me it cannot berestored after uninstall. I just would connect to the internet using a user and restore purchased items ... by request on the device saving these settings to the sharedpreferences. decoded by a forward only password encrypter or something else, which is only able to compare values but not to decrypt.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html

Comment: @Code.IT the in app purchases are stored on Google Play, I was thinking of caching them locally in order to avoid async query on each app start. Of course they can be restored on any of the user's devices. I am not sure what you mean by forward only password encrypter, but for the token I do need the actual value for web calls. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the link, it seems that in my case `InstanceID.getInstance(context).getId()` is a good key. Do I risk anything by using it? I'd love the hear your thoughts on this process given your experience on android and all the awesome answers you offer.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with anything that you are proposing. To paraphrase Tim O'Reilly, your problem is not with piracy, but obscurity.

Comment: I do have quite a lot of active users in the app and I want to have the data as secured as possible. I guess I could check for root and not allow the app to be used if rooted device... in this way, security risks are greatly reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Use Imei for unique device ID

from

```
public static String getDeviceIMEI(Context context) {

    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    if (telephonyManager.getDeviceId() != null)
        return telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

    return "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From what I am aware, not all devices have IMEI and from https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html says "#1: Avoid using hardware identifiers"...

Answer (score 0):

Settings.Secure #ANDROID_ID returns the Android ID as an [unique for each user](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) 64-bit hex string.

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```